# SVN delete files using GREP and REGEX

Tags: svn, grep

I'd like to use `svn delete` to delete all files start by `src\main\webapp\styles\images\outline` in my directory (all files that are deleted).

**First of all, I'd like to list all my files :**

`svn status | grep '^!,src\\main\\webapp\\styles\\images'`

And it seem's not working as expected, I get no lines.

**However, `svn status | grep '^!'` is working :**

[image]

Comment: What is the comma in your regexp? Note the third character: `^!,src...`

Comment: The comma is used for the second column in the response of `svn status`. The first column should have "!", and I need that the second column start by "src/mains/webapp/styles/images/outline".

Comment: I think you misunderstood the `,`. Could you replace it to ` *` ? So: `grep '^! *src\\main\\webapp\\styles\\images'` ?

Answer (score 0):

The columns are separated with *whitespace*, thus, use a `[[:space:]]*` between `!` and the second column data to match any *0 or more whitespace characters*:

```
grep '^![[:space:]]*src\\main\\webapp\\styles\\images\\outline'
```

See a demo screenshot:

[image]